# Google Docs IMPORTXML exact data value

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

first of all: I'm completely new to this, I just started with XML/HTML an hour ago and I tried to import  data from a website to work with it in Google Docs/tables. The website uses HTML and I try to import the exact value behind a displayed one and rounded version on the website i.e. for example instead of 86% displayed I want the value 0.8597.

In this example I  try to grab the Playoff chances for every NFL team in the 2021 season, recent week, based of FiveThirtyEight's predictions.
First off, I import the team names using this formula:
`=IMPORTXML("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2021-nfl-predictions/"; "//table[@id='standings-table']/tbody/tr/td[@class='team']/span[@class='full']")`

After that, I try to import the playoff chances with this formula:

`=IMPORTXML("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2021-nfl-predictions/"; "//table[@id='standings-table']/tbody/tr/td[@class='pct div']")`

That returns the following:

| TEAM | Playoff chances |
| --- | --- |
| Rams | 86% |
| Buccaneers | 83% |
| ... | ... |

But I want this:

| TEAM | Playoff chances |
| --- | --- |
| Rams | 0.8597 |
| Buccaneers | 0.82702 |
| ... | ... |

The whole element with the values looks like this, in this case for the Los Angeles Rams (LAR) `<td class="pct div" data-team="LAR" data-cat="make_playoffs" data-val="0.8597" style="background-color:rgb(36, 159, 219);color:#000;">86%</td>`

Instead of the `>86%<` I want to receive the `data-val="0.8597"`

I tried to describe my problem as good as I can, I hope you can understand it. Thanks for anyone reading this or even answering!

-Daxelinho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following xpath?

#### Modified xpath:

```
//table[@id='standings-table']/tbody/tr/td[@class='pct div']/@data-val
```

and

```
//td[@class='pct div']/@data-val
```

#### Result:

When the above xpath is used, the following result is obtained.

[image]

In this case, the sample formula is `=IMPORTXML("https://projects.fivethirtyeight.com/2021-nfl-predictions/", "//td[@class='pct div']/@data-val")`

Comment: Thank you so much! The `/@data-val` was what I was missing. I tried to get to the solution with trail and error but I haven't thought about this simple solution and the right syntax.
This vastly improves my workflow!

Comment: @Daxelinho Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.